# dingo error while get method with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, dingo-api

```
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function($api){
    $api->get('auth/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiUserController@getAuthUser');

    $api->get('auth/getInfo', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiUserAppointmentController@getInfo');

    $api->get('auth/show/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiUserAppointmentController@show');

});

public function show($id)
   {
    echo $id;die;
}

Error

    "message": "404 Not Found",
    "status_code": 404,
    "debug": {
        "line": 161,
        "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\G2Project\\medcrip\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
```

I stuck when adding parameter in get method don't know why this is say not found. if i remove {id} from route it works fine but when i do add {id} that says to me not found.

Please advice thanks in advance

Comment: What URI are you using when getting the error?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/auth/show/?id=53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `auth/show/{id}` route work, you should use this URI:

```
/api/auth/show/53
```

instead of this:

```
/api/auth/show/?id=53
```